# Removing non-word characters from a string

Tags: string-manipulation

I'm trying to get a list of words from a string. Sounds like an easy task for Mathematica. I have the following code:

```
text = "Merçi d'avoir pris le temps.";
ToLowerCase[#] & /@ StringSplit[text, Except[WordCharacter] ..]
```

However, the output is

```
{"merçi", "d", "avoir", "pris", "le", "temps"}
```

and not

```
{"merçi", "d'avoir", "pris", "le", "temps"}
```

because the `'` is not a word character. Hence, I'd like to ignore the `'`, just like the `-`. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Can you give a short but complete example of the problem/difficulty you are seeing (i.e. code I can copy and and run directly), and mention what OS and what version of Mathematica you are using?  I don't quite understand the question: what is the problem with `é`?  `WordCharacter` does match it on my machine, as `ToUpperCase`/`ToLowerCase` work fine on it.

Comment: @RunnyKine I'd rather have it omit all non-letter characters (except for `'` and `-`), as there are some pretty weird ones in these articles. I'd rather not have to specify them all manually.

Comment: @Szabolcs You're right, `é` is matched by `WordCharacter`, I must've had some other error in my code. The other problem persists: I don't want `'` and `-` taken out. Is there any way I can change `Except[WordCharacter]..` to something similar to `Except[{WordCharacter,Characters["'-"]}]..`?

Comment: @Szabolcs I've edited my question, hope it makes sense now.

Comment: @timvermeulen OK, sounds good.  I thought those characters would not be matched on some other OSs.  Could you simply use `Except[WordCharacter | "'" | "-"]`?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes! I hadn't thought of that.

In general, I have trouble figuring out when to use `|` and when to use `{...,...}`, or when to use `..` or `...`, etcetera. Anything you'd recommend me to read? The official reference pages aren't very n00b-friendly.

Comment: You can [start here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice)

Comment: @RunnyKine Wow, looks good. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
text = "Merçi d'avoir pris le temps."; 

ToLowerCase[#] & /@ StringSplit[text, Except[(LetterCharacter|"'"|"-")]..]
```

Gives:

```
{"merçi", "d'avoir", "pris", "le", "temps"}
```

OR if some of the words contain digits then replace `LetterCharacter` with `WordCharacter` above.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to extract words I would suggest using `StringCases` rather than `StringSplit`.  Also, there is no need to write `ToLowerCase[#] &` -- `ToLowerCase /@ list` would do.  In fact because `ToLowerCase` is `Listable` it can be directly applied to the output list.  Therefore I would write:

```
ToLowerCase @ StringCases[text, (WordCharacter | "'" | "-") ..]
```

> ```
> {"merçi", "d'avoir", "pris", "le", "temps"}
> ```

`StringCases` is somewhat faster than the alternative:

```
big = "" <> Table[text, {50000}];

StringSplit[big, Except[(LetterCharacter | "'" | "-")] ..] // Timing // First

StringCases[big, (WordCharacter | "'" | "-") ..]           // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.1342
>
> 0.1092
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It will be a discovery for some that:

```
DictionaryWordQ[#, Language -> "French"] & /@ {"merçi", "merci"}
```

> {False, True}

Other than that the following does the job:

```
w1 = TextCases[text, "Word"]
```

{"Merçi", "d'avoir", "pris", "le", "temps"}

---

Another example:

```
TextCases["Répétez s'il vous plaît. Quand voulez-vous voyager?", \
"Word"]
```

> {"Répétez", "s'il", "vous", "plaît", "Quand", "voulez-vous", 
> "voyager"}

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing some subtlety, this works:

```
    text = "Merçi d'avoir pris le temps.";
    StringSplit[text]
(* {Merçi, d'avoir, pris, le, temps.} *)
```

Comment: One still has to get rid of the terminal period. Ditto if the original text had commas, semicolons, dashes, etc. And then suppose one of the "words" were an abbreviation, e.g., `"Dr."`?