# Removing non-word characters in certain parts of a string

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I would like to ask how I can remove non-word characters from a string, but only in **certain cases**.

I have read this [article](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44046/removing-non-word-characters-from-a-string/44049#44049), so I know how to get the words out of a string. My text is however a bit more complicated.

For example:

```
trialtext = ",,temp sp.a tiral - dump NV-A rambo.6833. 16,rgcht";
```

From this text, I would like to get as output:

```
{"temp","sp.a","tiral","dump","NV-A","rambo","6833","16","rgcht"}
```

In other words, I want so split according to spaces, commas, hyphens and dots, EXCEPT when they have **letter** character before and after either a hyphen or a dot (so not commas or other signs!)

This has been my most succesful trial so far:

```
StringSplit[trialtext, 
 Except[WordCharacter, WordCharacter .. ~~ "." ~~ WordCharacter]]

{"temp sp.a tiral dump NV-A rambo.6833 16,rgcht"}
```

although I do not understand why - if I as for "." - it decides to also take "," and "-".

Therefore also the related question: can someone please explain to me why this

```
StringSplit[trialtext, Except[WordCharacter, ","]]
```

gives this output:

```
 {"temp sp.a tiral dump NV-A rambo.6833 16", "rgcht"}
```

while this:

```
StringSplit[trialtext, Except[WordCharacter, "."]]
```

produces this output:

```
{"temp", "sp", "a", "tiral", "dump", "NV", "A", "rambo", "6833", "16", "rgcht"}
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It seems `"."` is interpreted in `Except` as regular expression. And `"."` is every character excluding newline.

Answer (score 4):

[Regular expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#274403895) are cryptic, but they offer look-ahead and look-behind capabilities that are unavailable to regular string patterns:

```
split[s_] :=
  StringSplit[s, RegularExpression["( |,|(?<![[:alpha:]])[-.]|[-.](?![[:alpha:]]))+"]]

split[",,temp sp.a tiral - dump NV-A rambo.6833. 16,rgcht"]
(* {"temp", "sp.a", "tiral", "dump", "NV-A", "rambo", "6833", "16", "rgcht"} *)
```

This formulation respects the special rule that dots and dashes act as delimiters except when they have letters on both sides:

```
split["1.2.3.a.b.c   ---4-5-6-x-y-z---"]
(* {"1", "2", "3", "a.b.c", "4", "5", "6", "x-y-z"} *)
```

The key ingredient in this solution is the use of `(?<![[:alpha:]])[-.]` which can be interpreted as "a dot or dash that is not preceded by an alphabetic character".  Similarly, `[-.](?![[:alpha:]])` means "a dot or dash that is not followed by an alphabetic character".  Look-ahead and look-behind patterns are particularly useful for this problem because they allow us to examine characters for matching purposes without considering them to be part of a delimiter itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
trialtext = ",,temp sp.a tiral - dump NV-A rambo.6833. 16,rgcht";

StringTrim@StringSplit[trialtext, {"," | "-" | ".",
   x : PatternSequence[Except[WhitespaceCharacter] .. ~~ "." | "-" ~~LetterCharacter ..] :> x}]
(* {"temp", "sp.a", "tiral", "dump", "NV-A", "rambo", "6833", "16", "rgcht"} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

As of version 10.1 there is `TextWords` that will achieve this for you easily

```
TextWords[",,temp sp.a tiral - dump NV-A rambo.6833. 16,rgcht"]
(*{"temp", "sp.a", "tiral", "dump", "NV-A", "rambo.6833", "16,rgcht"}*)
```

Note that the implementation of the function is available to you with

```
??TextWords
```

It relies on a bunch of stuff from the `NaturalLanguageProcessing` package that rumour has it will be opened up more in Mathematica 11.